# How can I retrieve information from the Settings.app on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

I Googled a lot before asking but couldn't find a solution. I need to do this programmatically. I need the information recorded for Cellular Data Usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve such information because your app is subject to the [app sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/). Data usage information is considered private, and there is no public API to access it.

Comment: hmm I see. Anyway there are apps on the App Store which monitor Data Usage and I was wondering how they do that. Maybe using ifaddrs.h is the only way to do it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Depending on what applications you're looking at, they may have access to data that you do not. In particular, applications written by cellular providers (e.g, Verizon, AT&T, etc) may be going off of the network's own billing data, rather than anything available on the phone.

Comment: I was talking of applications like this one: Data Usage by sigterm https://appsto.re/gr/Gwgex.i